# Adding new files during Pull request and merge

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, git-merge-conflict

In bitbucket one of our developer created a feature branch from dev, then did few changes in existing files in feature branch, added few extra files to the features branch through push remote.
Then he raised a pull request to merge to dev branch.
Pull request and merge were successful without conflict but the new files are missing in dev branch; although changes in exiting files are reflecting properly in dev.

How can we add missing files through pull request only or is there any other way (except local pull and push)?

Comment: The Pull Request is closed and merged to `dev` branch? And you have pull the *new* `dev` branch after merging from feature branch from your developer friend?

Answer (score 0):

if your PR is still alive - then we can try adding missing files to same local feature branch and git push (this merge to same PR (refresh PR to notice new changes))

Answer (score 0):

If your Pull Request not completed and merged to base-branch, you can just by `git push` add new files to that Pull Request (condition: the `git push` must be in the same branch as the Pull Request is).
If the Pull Request is accepted by another developer and you have merged it to the source code (mostly to `develop` branch), you can't add new files to this Pull Request.